# Doctrine: ordering By Count on Associated entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

**Goal:** Ordering my entities on how ofter they are used on associated relations (oneToMany)

**The problem:** DQL, it somehow handles the FROM keyword is an entity or class.

**The Exception thrown:** QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0 col 103 near 'FROM MyBundle:Entity Error: Class 'FROM' is not defined.

---

Here is a SQL query I wrote to test how to get the data. It works perfectly

```
SELECT en.id, (COUNT(DISTINCT ag.artist_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT rg.release_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT tg.track_id)) AS total

FROM myapp.entity AS en

LEFT JOIN myapp.other_one AS o1 ON o1.entity_id = en.id
LEFT JOIN myapp.other_two AS o2 ON o2.entity_id = en.id

GROUP BY en.id

ORDER BY total DESC ;
```

---

To get the data in symfony to hydrate to objects I try to use Doctrine Query Language in the EntityRepository like this:

```
/**
 * Find Most Common Entities
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function findMostCommon()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->select('en, (COUNT(DISTINCT en.other1) + COUNT(DISTINCT en.other2)) AS count')
        ->from('MarulaBundle:Entity', 'en')
        ->leftJoin('MyBundle:Other1', 'o1', 'WITH', 'o1.entity = en.id')
        ->leftJoin('MyBundle:Other2', 'o2', 'WITH', 'o2.entity = en.id')
        ->groupBy('en')
        ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

---

Since it is possible in a SQL query. I was hoping it would work just as fine with DQL.

Has anyone experienced this error before? Is it even possible to achieve this with Doctrine, or is doctrine limited relating this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOPS: I should not use the keyword "count"

**Solution:**

```
->select('en, (COUNT(DISTINCT en.other1) + COUNT(DISTINCT en.other2)) AS HIDDEN orderCount')
```

**note:** adding the HIDDEN keyword helps to get only the entities back, which makes the hydration fit right in